# Can i get multiple VMs on the same monitor without changing the resolution of the VM displays?

Tags: windows-7, vmware-workstation

Was wondering if anyone knew how to get 3-4 virtual machines to share the same monitor (i.e. so that I could potentially get all 4 displays on one screen, each screen environment would need to maintain its 1280x1024 internal resolution (so scale I guess?) anyways if you could help it would be greatly appreciated. I'm new to VMWare so please be gentle :-P

Comment: VMWare and virtual box ?

Comment: Sorry Virtual Machine on VMWare was what i ment

Comment: As i recall, vmware would make VM terminals have scrollbars if they are smaller than the resolution of the VM.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried access with scaled VNC access?

For each VM, allow VNC access, on the host, use the VNC client, force scaling of the video.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WMware Workstation you can show each virtual machine at separate window.

Other possibility is remote desktop, but this depends, which operation system do you use in virtual machines and on the host system.

Virtual Machines

Windows - Remote Desktop - best performance nad user experience.
Linux/Unix - VNC (lightVNC, RealVNC), if you using some window system
Linux/Unix - putty or something like that, if you using console in virtual system